# Axon: Use AxonServer instead of defined JPA datasource in a Spring Boot application

Tags: axon

I would like to use AxonServer as an EventStore in a Spring Boot application, but Axon auto-configuration uses JPA datasource, if defined. I don't know how to force Axon auto-configuration to use AxonServer instead of JPA?

**Update:**

With amazing advice from **Steven** (thanks a lot), I managed to little bit clarify what I would like to ask:

If I define a datasource and JPA entries in Spring Boot application config as in the example below, the tables `token_entry`, `saga_entry`, etc. are then created in the database. I would like to set AXON not to use this datasource and not create any tables in it.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: test
    password: test
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc"
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer relies a bit on what version of Axon Framework you are using.
If you use 4.0 and above, the auto configuration will look for an Axon Server instance in your environment. You will thus not have to force it at all.

If you are however using 3.3.x or 3.4.x, you will have to leverage the [Axon Hub Client](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axoniq-axonhub-client). More specifically, the `axonhub-spring-boot-autoconfigure` dependency should be included.

However, I would recommend upgrading to the latest Axon Framework 4 release, as feature development only takes place there at the moment.

Comment: Hi Steven, 
thank you for your advices. I am trying to use the 4.1 version. But I am newbie in Axon. When I run the Spring Boot application without JPA, then it works nicely. But when I try to add the "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" and "postgresql" dependencies, then the Axon uses JPA datasource instead. I would like to force it to use AxonServer, because the JPA datasource should be used for other purposes. I gues I have to configure somehow it, but i don't know how to :-(. I have tried to find any guide or documentation, but without success.

Comment: I oftentimes pair up the `axon-spring-boot-starter` with the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, but never did that not set up a connection with Axon Server as the Event Storage mechanism. I suggest to update your question, sharing your entire dependency set if possible. Look at this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqn9p8Duy54) video guide I set up for example. The Github repository referenced there also uses both dependencies at the same time.